# Fuse esb doesn't take settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I want to install hawtio using repository in my local net typing in console osgi:install mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-web/1.2.3. This repository is not behind proxy. But I receive an error:

settings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>company-nexus</id>
        <name>some name Nexus Repo</name>
        <mirrorOf>*,!np-snapshots,!public-snapshots</mirrorOf>
        <url>http:/mysite/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>companyRepo</id>
        <properties>
            <nexus.repo>mysite</nexus.repo>
        </properties>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>np-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://${nexus.repo}/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>public-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://${nexus.repo}/nexus/content/groups/public_snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>np-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://${nexus.repo}/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>public-snapshots</id>
                <url>http://${nexus.repo}/nexus/content/groups/public_snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>companyRepo</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

 <proxies>
<proxy>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <host>proxy.mysite</host>
    <port>3128</port>
    <username>myProxyUsername</username>
    <password>myProxyPassword</password>
 <nonProxyHosts>nexus.mySite</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg file:
http://pastebin.com/q5GZnVGX

Error:
http://pastebin.com/3mk7DnUi

I'm using jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024

Answer (score 0):

To clarify - Does your local repository have direct access to the Internet, and is it setup to mirror all of the default fuse repositories (e.g. the ones in 'org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories')?

It's also useful to enable debug logging as I believe you'll then be able to see the repositories fuse is using to resolve the bundle (e.g. log:set debug)

Personally i'd trial and error. First i'd add 'http:/mysite/nexus/content/groups/public' to the 'org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories' setting, remove the mirror from settings.xml and see if it works. If it does, it indicates an issue taking the mirror settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Hawito documention](http://hawt.io/getstarted/index.html), you should try

```
features:addurl mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.3.0/xml/features
features:install hawtio
```